# Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I want to use a playground in Xcode 6.0.1.
So File -> New -> Playground

I get immediately the error.
Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited unexpectedly.
See image. Restart Xcode didn't helped.

Whats wrong with Xcode?[image: Xcode Error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A restart of the mac solves the problem. What causes the issue is still unknown.

Comment: I am having this issue with XCode 7 Beta 4. Restarting the mac and reinstalling XCode beta did not help ..

Comment: After downloading XCode 7 Beta 5 (Pre-Release), this issue doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: Having the issue right now with Xcode 7 Beta 5 :( Restarting the computer didn't help.

Comment: Having the same problem with Xcode 7.1 and El Capitan. I restarted Mac and Xcode and the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 29):

*New Answer:*

As @Woomin points out in the comments, first try restarting Xcode and rebooting your Mac, and if that fails try the following:

Try deleting the .simruntime files:

[image]

I found them located here in my root directory:

[image]

*Old Answer:*

If the above doesn't work try removing everything in the `Developer` folder located at `/Library/Developer/`. If this still doesn't work try removing everything in `~/Library/Developer/`. If this still doesn't solve it remove xcode with AppCleaner and reinstall it using the MAS version. I found that doing this last thing solved the issue but it came back when I installed the simulators from xcode's download tab. Removing the .simruntime files finally solved it for me. BTW, I'm using version 7.2.

Comment: Usually restarting XCode works, and if that won't do I restart my Mac. This is obviously the way when both fail.

Comment: @WoominJoshPark Good point. Try the simple restart option first and then if that fails this is the way to solve it. I'll add your point to my answer. Thanx.

Comment: I also have the issue, but my CoreSimulator folder only has a Devices folder in it, hence I can't delete any .simruntime files. Restarting Xcode and my mac didn't solve the problem either. As I have many archives from apps submitted to the AppStore in my Developer folder, I don't want to delete it entirely. Any idea?

Comment: @florianpfisterer My suggestion is to use a search tool to search for the .simruntime file types on your system. I like "Find Any File", but you could also use terminal or EasyFind to do the same thing. Find where those files are located and delete them. I'm not sure why you don't have the profiles folder in CoreSimulator. Puzzling. Hope it works because this bug can be a show stopper. The other options is to do a TimeMachine backup. Delete as in the Old Answer and if you run into trouble you can always restore from the backup. You might also want to use something like SuperDuper to do a dupe.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Tried that already, didn't find the files. Now deleted Xcode entirely with AppCleaner after saving the archives seperately. Problem is now solved.

Comment: @florianpfisterer Once in a while it's always good to just blow Xcode away and start again.  :(

Comment: Xcode 7.2 (7C68), OS X 10.10.5: I noticed this problem started happening after I downloaded the iOS 9.1 simulator from within Xcode. I have confirmed that if I just move that simulator out of the way (I just moved it to Desktop), the playground works fine. Move it back, and I get the error.

Comment: @mbeaty Makes sense. The files I deleted are some sort of runtime cache for the 9.1 simulator. I'm noticing xCode is showing I haven't downloaded the 9.1 simulator. Are you able to get it to work with the 9.1 simulator installed and removing the above listed runtime files?

Comment: @mbeaty I ran into the same problem tonight when the iOS playground stopped working after downloading the iOS 9.1 simulator in Xcode.  Removing that runtime resolved the issue.

Comment: @smileBot Are you saying with 8.3, 8.4, and 9.0 runtimes removed, leaving just 9.1 runtime?

Comment: @mbeaty I just removed all of the ones I show in the screenshot above and that solved the problem for me. You have to experiment. Try just removing the 9.1 version and see if that clears the issue up. If not remove the rest and that should do it.

Comment: Resolved for Xcode 7.2.1 on OS X 10.11.3. The issue had persisted for several months (and several OS X updates) so a reboot was not going to be a solution. I closed Xcode, went to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes directory (note - this is the root directory, not within the user profile - I kept looking for ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator etc before realizing there was no ~ ). There were 5 *.simruntime files, which I just moved (using sudo mv) to another directory. Restarted Xcode and playground works perfectly now. Hope it won't come back as soon as I post this update!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [smileBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951349/smilebot)'s answer. I am able to make it work with 7.2 too. I did try differently.

I installed Xcode 7.2 release version via downloading. However it had problem mentioned above. I first deleted the Xcode 7.2 via AppCleaner completely. Empty the trash. Also cleaned the derived data using [WatchDog for Xcode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/watchdog-for-xcode/id734258109?mt=12) And then restart the machine. Try again, it did not work.

So I went ahead deleted the folder `~/Library/Developer/` and then restart, try again, I can use Playground again in Xcode 7.2 again.

Comment: Note the second time I didn't delete the XCode 7.2, I just deleted the `~/Library/Developer/` folder

Comment: This worked for me. Also after deleting ~/Developer I restarted my mac (thought I was using Windows 95 for a sec there)

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7.2 and Mac os x 10.11.2 
Restart Xcode or mac does not worked for me.
I solve this problem is that delete the Simulator Profiles. The Path is ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes. Delete all Runtimes. Than Restart the Xcode, problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Install Command line tools using command

> xcode-select --install

then u will get an update in Appstore install that app Problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

OSX 10.11.2 and Xcode 7.2

I had gotten a reply to his from a member on the Apple Developer Forum and wanted to provide some additional information on my fix for this.  First I deleted the `~/Library/Developer` folder as indicated.  Looking into it it had the some `Simulator Profiles`.  I didn't know what that had to do with the Playground issue so **I did NOT empty the Trash**.  I rebooted and the playground worked.

I put back the folder and the playground had the issues again. I one by one removed the simulator profiles in the sub directory ultimately removing **ALL of the profiles** without deleting the `~/Library/Developer` folder structure and the Playground works.

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 7.2 (7C68) i had the same problem. I'd solve it by changing the entry of the *runtime* value from c*om.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-1* to *com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-2*. I'd changed it in the device.plist. In ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/XCPGDevices/ is one or more folder with a UUID as name. In one of this folders is the current device.plist.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to delete manually Developer's folder. Just follow this steps in Command Line (CL).

Quit Xcode.app, Simulator.app and all Xcode related and then in CL:

```
 sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

 rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: In my case, I also deleted a theme folder which I have installed through Alcatraz, it was in /Library/Developer/Xcode/ now it's in UserData. But it was a nasty Xcode bug. I did a lot of stuff, I hope this works >.<

Comment: uninstalled Xcode, delete developer folder and did a clean install it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

A restart of Xcode solves the problem , most of the times . (Do remember to quit from the dock too)

If that doesn't work a restart of Mac is all that is required

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I found that the platform setting wasn't set for my playground. Probably because the playground was created in a previous version of XCode which didn't require it.

Solution:

Double click on your playground to open it in XCode and wait for the fail message.
Dismiss the message (it may appear more than once) and do the following

1.Select to show the project navigator pane.

[image]

2.Select the workspace in the navigator.

[image]

3.Select to show the Utilities pane.

[image]

4.In the playground settings area of the Identity inspector. Select OSX (or iOS)

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It is ok when *Change the platform to "**OS X**" from inspector*, but problem when back to "**iOS**". I don't know why...in Xcode7 Beta.

Plus, it is ok in my **Xcode 6.4** for both platform when playground.

And there is one more option for **iOS platform** "Run in Full Simulator",besides "Render Documentation"option. in My **Xcode 6.4 inspector**

and I have check the "IDEPlaygroundSettings.inspector" in

> /Applications/**Xcode.app**/Contents//PlugIns/IDELanguageSupportUI.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/IDEPlaygroundSettings.inspector
>
> and
>
> /Applications/**Xcode-Beta.app**/Contents//PlugIns/IDELanguageSupportUI.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/IDEPlaygroundSettings.inspector
>
> they are quite different.